# Rename all files and replace hyphen - with underscore _

Tags: linux, bash, centos

So I have a bunch of files in a directory, pdf, docx etc and I am trying to rename them and replace dash '`-`' with underscore '`_`'.

example: `700006233-20161026092752.pdf` >> `700006233_20161026092752.pdf`

this is the code I am using but doesn't seem to be working.

```
$ for file in /directory/*; do echo mv "$file" "$(echo $file | sed 's/-/_/g')" ; done
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `rename`:

```
rename "s/-/_/g" *
```

Or use  `mv "$file" "${file//-/_}"` in the `for` loop.

Comment: The second of those doesn't mention removing `echo` - which is the primary reason why none of the filenames are being changed